# Telerik RadGrid how to change position of Column when Columns and AutoGeneratedColumns is populated

Tags: c#, telerik, radgrid

In RagGrid I have populated AutoGeneratedColumns and add Columns. Columns are showed first and then AutoGeneratedColumns are showed. I want to change columns order. How to change that second column from Columns will be showed after 4th column in AutoGeneratedColumns:

1 Column
2 Column
3 AutoGeneratedColumn
4 AutoGeneratedColumn
..
7 Column
8 AutoGeneratedColumn

Thanks